# Regex Selection of Strings

Tags: python, regex

Trying to use regex to select values between `<title> </title>`.

However sometimes these two tags are on different lines.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1290264

Comment: @bcorso This is not as egregious as the usual case -- per http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-title-element , `<title>` can't have any attributes, nor may it be nested within itself.

Comment: That said, in Python there is no reason not to use the perfectly good [HTML parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) from the standard library.  Everything will be easier.

Comment: @zack Unfortunately my task does not permit me to import extra modules. Is there no simple way to have regex search a block of html and show me the values it finds between the HTML tags Title/

Comment: Wait, if you can't `import`, how are you using regular expressions? You need `import re` for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have stated, it's more powerful and less brittle to use a full fledged markup language parser, like the [htmlparser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) from stdlib or even [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), over regex. Though, since regex seems to be a requirement, maybe something like this will work:

```
import urllib2
import re

URL = 'http://amazon.com'
page = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
stream = page.readlines()
flag = False
for line in stream:
    if re.search("<title>", line):
        print line
        if not re.search("</title>", line):
            flag = True
    elif re.search("</title>", line):
        print line
        flag = False
    elif flag == True:
        print line
```

When it finds the `<title>` tag it prints the line, checks to make sure the closing tag isn't on the same line, and then continues to print lines until it finds the closing `</title>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use a parser, just do it by brute force. Read the HTML doc into the string `doc` then:

```
try:
    title = doc.split('<title>')[1].split('</title>')[0]
except IndexError:
    ## no title tag, handle error as you see fit
```

Note that if there is an opening title tag without a matching closing tag, the search succeeds. Not a likely scenario in a well-formatted HTML doc, but FYI.